# Android USB Communication Other than ADB

Tags: android

Is there any way to communicate between PC and Android tablet through USB other than ADB ?. By googleing  I found that we need to use TCP/IP,port forwarding, socket programming etc...

Basically I want communicate in both USB Host and Accessory mode.

Comment: Android devices can act as USB hosts, but you'll probably have to roll up your sleeves and write a custom program if you don't want to use ADB. What do you want to use that for?

Comment: So using ADB is the preferred method right?. Suppose I want to communicate with some embedded device like raspberry pi or beglboard and I want to control some peripheral then which should be the best method ?.

Comment: Basically, you want your Android device to be able to control another device by USB (Raspi,...), just like apps like _DSLR Controller_ do?

Comment: Yes I need to communicate between them using some command.

Comment: Hm, so I don't see why you would need ADB since you want to communicate directly from your Android device to the other device. Maybe start by reading [USB Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) in the docs?

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. So I can communicate over USB without using ADB

Comment: I'll add an answer about that then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices can power and communicate with USB devices, just like a computer would. Start by reading [USB Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) on the Android documentation.

However, devices like the Raspberry Pi can connect to an existing network (WiFi, Ethernet), so depending on your needs you could just write/install some externally accessible API and access that from your Android device through WiFi.

[Microbridge](http://code.google.com/p/microbridge/) also sounds interesting in relation with what you want to do.

Comment: But I need to communicate through USB. So as you said I will refer the Doc. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi F.X I have one more doubt. Using ADB are they using Ethernet over USB?.

Comment: I don't think so, not by default. You can forward ports or connect to a remote ADB server though. (By the way, have you looked at [this](http://code.google.com/p/microbridge/)?)

Comment: Hi thanks for the link that really interesting..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via Wifi.

Check this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UI70UYug_zQ)

It explains how to run a SSH server on your Android device using SSHDroid or QuickSSHd

[QuickSSHd from google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd)

[SSHDroid from google play too](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=SSHDroid&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid&hl=es&ei=682dUcSyBsabtAaNloFo&usg=AFQjCNGJQRs0JGQwC08v3bbbP5VDVsUKrg&sig2=YKU4sQQ07g3tzJi7vXpQ8A&bvm=bv.46865395,d.Yms)

Answer (score 0):

If data volume is low and several seconds latency is ok, you might just copy files back and forth through MTP protocol. Easily available on almost all Android devices.